# How to install adminer under ubuntu locally?

Tags: php, adminer

under my local kubuntu18 I installed adminer:

```
# sudo apt-get install adminer
 ...
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# whereis  adminer
adminer: /etc/adminer /usr/share/adminer
```

I found this branch
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813282/how-to-configure-adminer-to-be-reachable-on-the-local-network

and running I got error that symbolic link already exists

```
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# cd /etc/apache2/conf-available
root@AtHome:/etc/apache2/conf-available# sudo ln -s ../../adminer/apache.conf adminer.conf
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'adminer.conf': File exists
```

I found file /etc/apache2/conf-available/adminer.conf
which shows 25 bytes and open it I see that it is empty.

I expect my adminer will work under url

```
http://localhost/adminer
```

How to config it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I installed apache2 and I configured the folder /var/www/adminer as http://localhost/adminer/ and it works very well. But I did all and I only used apt for downloading apache2 and mysql.